# How to take pictures from front and back cameras at the same time? Samsung can with their dual shot feature

Tags: android

All over the net I am seeing people say that this is not possible yet if you look at Samsung's Galaxy Line and their Dual Shot feature it shows that the software is capable of opening both cameras and showing them at the same time.

I have tried writing an app that opens both cameras and ran it on a gs4 but I get an error when I try to open the second one. This must be possible if samsung can do it.

Comment: Not necessarily... Samsung modifies the Android OS that they distribute, the very well could've done it without public APIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Android hasn't yet exposed a way to do this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open(int)

> Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time
>   for a particular hardware camera.

Comment: But as I said, I am able to use the Dual Shot feature on a Galaxy S4 which does indeed turn on both cameras at the same time so it must be possible somehow.